# Recuperar valor de um HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Achei uma pergunta de 4 anos atrás que "seria" exatamente o que preciso:

> Tenho uma URL onde retorna um HTTP QueryString, e necessito recuperar
>   as informações da URL e converter em variáveis para fazer consultas no
>   banco de dados. Em PHP basta utilizar o $_GET[""], agora em C# eu não
>   sei como proceder.
>
> Vou dar um exemplo para esclarecer melhor.
>
> Possuo a URL: http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe&age=12
>
> Tenho que pegar os valores "Joe" e "12" para uma consulta posterior.

E nessa pergunta tem a seguinte resposta:

> string nome = Request.QueryString["name"];
>
> string idade = Request.QueryString["age"];

Porém estou colocando esse "Request" na minha view, e apresenta o seguinte erro: "O nome Request não existe no contexto atual".

Coloquei os namespace @using System.Net e @using System.IO que achei em outras pesquisas no google, mas ainda sem sucesso, continua erro no Request.
Mesmo com Alt+Enter do VS não dá nenhuma sugestão de correção.

Alguma sugestão. 
Agradeço.

[UPDATE]
A pedido estou colocando o código da view que estou precisando recuperar o valor passado pela URL.

```
@using SoftiseEVO.Classes;
@using System.Net;
@using System.IO;

@model IEnumerable<LanctoConferenciaCaixaModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Consulta Caixa";

    string _idCaixa = Request.QueryString["idCaixa"]; //<= o erro está na chamaa do Request: "O nome Request não existe no contexto atual".

    string _dscaixa = "C002 CAIXA ANDERSON N"; //após ter o idCaixa, preciso buscar a descrição
    string _vlconferido = "0,00";

<div class="box box-primary">
    <!-- box consulta -->
    <form asp-controller="FechamentoCaixa" asp-action="LanctoConfCaixaAdministrativo" role="form" method="get" id="FormLanctoCaixa">
        <div class="box box-default" style="border-top: 0px;">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title box-success">Lançamento Conferência Caixa Administrativo</h3>
                <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">

                        <input type="hidden" id="IDCXACAD" name="IDCXACAD" value="" />
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync(InputText.ViewComponentName, new { label = "Caixa", id = "IDCXACFGDIA", value = _dscaixa, readOnly = true, uppercase = true })
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync(InputTextConsulta.ViewComponentName, new { label = "Forma Pagamento", id = "IDFORPGT", valueId = "", valueCod = "", valueText = "", hiddenCod = false, onlynumberCod = true, maxlengthCod = "7", readonlyText = true, required = true, uppercase = true, autofocusCod = true })
                        @await Component.InvokeAsync(InputValue.ViewComponentName, new { label = "Valor Conferido", id = "VLCONFERIDO", value = _vlconferido })

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-left: -10px;margin-right:-10px">
                    <div class="box-footer no-border">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-softise" id="BtnConsultar">CONFIRMAR</button>

                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="FechamentoCaixa" asp-action="GetFechamentoCaixa">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">CANCELAR</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- fim box consulta -->

</div>
}
```